# ASP.NET Web Service parser error on server, not locally

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, deployment, asmx

**EDIT2**

Looks like I can't read properly, disregard this post, I will try to make a WCF service instead.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

Ok it seems I should start learning MVC instead. I tried getting into it before when I could't get this to work but maybe I didn't try hard enough because I already completed my web services and didn't feel like starting over before I knew if the problem was trivial.

*For those who are interested:*

What I am actually trying to accomplish is to create a database with a dozen different highscore tables which I will be able to retrieve from my Android app as JSON. So far I have an XML database and a webmethod for asking if a score is in the top 50 on a specific highscore table. One for submitting your score, and one for retrieving the entire highscore to show in the app. I also have a simple interface for adding, removing etc from the database.

**Updated question:** *Will I be able to reuse some of my code if I create an MVC project and how do I put said project on the server? can it be done with an FTP client or do I need to use Web Deploy, IIS or web matrix or some other software? and what are the requirements of the server?*

Thank you so much for the help :)

----------Original Post--------------

Recently I have been trying to learn how to create a web service in Microsoft Visual Web Developer (2010 express on win7 64bit) in a *web application*. I have a few very simple JSON web methods and when I run the project locally from Visual Web Developer it works like a charm, they return the correct values etc.

But when I transfer the project to my windows server running .NET 4.0 (which is the same as my target framework in this project) I can't access the web service anymore, the *.aspx* web pages work great but the *.asmx* web service shows the following error:

(I can only post two hyperlinks yet so I removed this image)

That line 1 is the only line in the .asmx file btw. I have tried putting the Namespace.Classname there instead but the error remains. (*Test.DBWebService* instead of just DBWebService)

I haven't changed anything in the code, this exact code does work on my computer. I have tried things that helped others with similar issues, like the build options:

**Before running startup page:** Build Web Site

**Target Framework:** .NET 4.0

**Build Web Site as part of a framework** Checked

which I assume should be configured like that.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings/>
    <client/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is the .cs file for the web service and an example method which works *locally* but can't be accessed on the server.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T6pq.png

What could possible create this problem? Am I missing something vital here because I am not very experienced. I have tried for days to get this done and even asked my web hosting company but they said they don't help with programming related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just now learning web services, then you should stop right now. You've made a major mistake.

You are using "ASMX Web Services", a technology which is all but obsolete. No new development should be done using ASMX unless there is no other choice.

Another mistake you are making is in using the web site "project". I strongly recommend you not use those for anything other than simple sites, and you might want to avoid them for that purpose in any case. Among other things, they have this precise issue with not building what you think they should build when you think they should build it.

Use a web application project instead, using "Add New Project" instead of "Add New Web Site".

Comment: Actually I do lots of ASMX stuff. Why do you state that this should be obsolete? Likely you are refering to WCF. I prefer to use a screwdriver when I only need a screwdriver to solve a task, even if a crane is available for purchase.

Comment: See [tag:asmx] and maybe http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/. And if you think WCF is only for cranes, you really missed the point. It's quite capable of producing a service as simple as an ASMX service.

Comment: I have tried looking into MVC and web application and I've managed to create a web app with the same web services as this web site. But I still have problems deploying it. For the web site I just use an FTP client to put everything on the server. But it doesn't seem to work that way with the other types of projects. I tried using "web deploy" but it gave me an error that web deploy was not activated on the server.

Comment: I would be extremely grateful for help with a simple webservice. I don't mind switching to MVC but I'm not sure how to make it work on the server with each type of project.

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not the one who suggested MVC. I would not suggest MVC for web services.

Comment: Do you suggest using a wep application project? when I add new items in such a project the file created is an .asmx file. I might go with that approach if I can keep more of my old code.

Comment: Oh I must have misread WCF for MVC, sorry about that. I will have a look at that and try to learn it instead.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most probable causes of your issue are:
- wrong configuration of the site (application) within the IIS. My guess is that you are deploying onto an application but for some reason the application is not correctly created and the ASP.NET is unable to initialize the /bin folder where the binaries should exist
- wrong configuration of the IIS/ASP.NET. Find another machine with similar configuration and check your site there. If it works correctly, you could go back and try to find/resolve issues with your local ASP.NET configuration.